# Showing Custom field within Context box

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `the_meta()`  to show custom field results. My aim is to show the values/results in a content-box div.

```
<div class="content-box">
<?php the_meta(); ?> </div>
```

This works for the post with custom fields , but then it also shows blank boxes on other pages without custom fields as well.

How do I show these content boxes only on pages with custom fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`get_post_custom_keys`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom_keys) to check if there is meta (or not):

```
<?php
    if ( get_post_custom_keys() ) {
        echo '<div class="content-box">';
        the_meta();
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Or, to deal with the hidden meta values issue (cf. comments), you could roll your own meta function. Put the following in the `functions.php` file of your theme:

```
function so16500287_the_meta() {
    if ( $keys = get_post_custom_keys() ) {
        $array = array();                   
        foreach ( (array) $keys as $key ) {
            $keyt = trim($key);
            if ( is_protected_meta( $keyt, 'post' ) )
                continue;
            $values = array_map('trim', get_post_custom_values($key));
            $value = implode($values,', ');
            $array[] = apply_filters('the_meta_key', "<li><span class='post-meta-key'>$key:</span> $value</li>\n", $key, $value);
        }
        if( ! empty( $array ) ) {
            echo "<div class='content-box'><ul class='post-meta'>\n";
            foreach( $array as $item )
                echo $item;
            echo "</ul></div>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

and call it in your template with:

```
<?php so16500287_the_meta(); ?>
```

Comment: Tried the code , but it unfortunately still returns blank content boxes on pages without custom fields

Comment: In some cases, there are hidden custom fields, which have keys starting with `_`

Comment: Jeez thanks - starting to get a bit too technical now...

Comment: updated my answer with a solution that deals with the hidden meta